# "'ViewController' may not respond to ..." warning when I *have* declared the method in @interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm probably making a dumb mistake here, but I've been staring at my code and can't figure out what the problem is. I have a method defined in the @interface of my ViewController .h file as such:

```
- (void) displaySubviewPopup:(PopupView *)currentPopup forTimerID:(int)timerID;
```

Then in my .m file I implement the method as such:

```
- (void) displaySubviewPopup:(PopupView *)currentPopup forTimerID:(int)timerID {

...method implemented here...

}
```

And then elsewhere in my code I'm calling the method as such:

```
   [self displaySubviewPopup:currentPopup fortimerID:timerID];
```

But for some weird reason I'm getting the ol' "May not respond to..." compiler warning "warning: 'SwimTimerViewController' may not respond to '-displaySubviewPopup:fortimerID:'"

I'm probably missing something simple here, but like I said, I've been staring at my code and my brain is starting to fizzle trying to figure out what I overlooked here. It seems like my method implementation is correct...

Any ideas? I can post more code if need be, but that's the gist of it.

Thanks!

Comment: How are the currentPopup and timerID variables defined ? Maybe currentPopup is defined as a UIView or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really easy answer for clean eyes, happens really often though.

Just change your capitalization:

```
   [self displaySubviewPopup:currentPopup forTimerID:timerID];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: haha, yup, definitely a brain fart mistake. That's what I get for coding before coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`fortimerID` does not match your definition. Notice the lower case `t`.

Just fix the capitalization issue and you should be all set:

`[self displaySubviewPopup:currentPopup forTimerID:timerID];`

Comment: Thanks Mark. Again, that's what I get for coding minus caffeine :)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is copy pasted, then it's a typo : you used fortimerID instead of forTimerID (capital T)